# Formatting text in message box

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, messagebox

[Result so Far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnFR2.jpg)
[The Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5aT6.jpg)
I have gotten this far with some help and I'm not quite sure on what to do to add some organization.

So the following code works. When I double-click an employee's name that is hyperlinked a message box appears with a list of information from a different sheet. What I want to do is place the column header from that list in front of each of the listed items.

the loop 1 to 12 basically grabs a list of different information and I'm looking for a way to title each item in that list to make the list more clear.
Here is the code I have now

```
   ****Dim iLoop As Integer
Dim strHolder As String     '<~ string that will hold the details
    For iLoop = 1 To 12          '<~ change this to your requirements
strHolder = strHolder & rEmployee.Offset(0, iLoop - 1).Value & vbNewLine
Next
MsgBox strHolder
End Sub****
```

Comment: Can you show the data, difficult to deduce from code, I'd say an `cells(1,remployee.column)` but w/o data cant be sure.

Comment: *What I want to do is place the column header in front of the information displayed in the message box* - erm, what? Can you please better explain exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: I think he wants MsgBox colHead & "whatever else"

Comment: Whatever. There's so much noise it's hard to even tell where the `MsgBox` call is. Consider replacing all that fluff with a [mcve] that actually illustrates the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Looks like you have several choices: (a) Before your " For iLoop = 1 To 12", then set strHolder to the 'column header value' (plus a space or colon or..., or (b) after the loop set strholder like: strHolder = "blah blah blah: " & strholder.

Comment: sorry guys I thought I had placed 2 pictures in there but apparently not, I understand the "lot of noise" I'll reduce this. The pictures are in there now and Wayne I think you're on to something I'm going to try it out here.

Comment: I edited the question some hopefully it is more clear Wayne I will try your response now

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn That did the trick if you won't to copy that as an answer I'll check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, to get the column heading placed before the content of the 12 cell's in your MsgBox, you can use the values found in row 1 of that sheet. If you want something other than the first row as the prefix, you will need to adjust the code to.

```
For iLoop = 1 To 12          
    strHolder = strHolder & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Employee and Job List").Cells(1, iLoop) & _
                ": " & vbTab & rEmployee.Offset(0, iLoop - 1).Value & vbNewLine
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could probably put a simple extra bit of code in your `strHolder` string builder. I've had to edit the code I've put together a little bit to make it complete but you should get the general jist of it. By using the `Cells(1, iLoop).value & ": " & ...` it'll put the column header into the message box prefixing the data that it's picking up too.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim rEmployee As Range
    Set rEmployee = Cells(2, 1)
    Dim iLoop As Integer
    Dim strHolder As String     '<~ string that will hold the details
    For iLoop = 1 To 12          '<~ change this to your requirements
    strHolder = strHolder & Cells(1, iLoop).Value & ": " & rEmployee.Offset(0, iLoop - 1).Value & vbNewLine
    Next
    MsgBox strHolder

End Sub
```

Keep up the coding.

Cheers Chris